# Devops Proxy Configuration for tasks, not for agent

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, tfvc

This my scenario:

- Azure DevOps Server Version Dev17.M153.3
- Self-hosted Agent Agent.Version 2.177.1
- Source Control Type TFVC

The Agent is working well without proxy configuration, the problem are 2 tasks it executes.

After getting the source code, the pipeline have two NuGet tasks:

- First the [NuGet Tool Installer task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/nuget?view=azure-devops)
- Second the [NuGet Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget?view=azure-devops)

I get the following error in the first task

```
##[debug]Agent.Version=2.177.1
##[debug]Agent.ToolsDirectory=C:\Proyectos\Agent2\_work\_tool
##[debug]isExplicit: 5.10.0
##[debug]explicit? true
##[debug]evaluating 1 versions
##[debug]matched: 5.10.0
##[debug]Querying versions list
##[debug]Agent.ProxyUrl=undefined
ERR:connect ETIMEDOUT 152.199.23.209:443
##[debug]task result: Failed
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]
```

Then I configure these Pipeline variables

```
Agent.ProxyBypassList   $(ProxyBypassList)
Agent.ProxyPassword     $(ProxyPassword)
Agent.ProxyUrl          $(ProxyUrl)
Agent.ProxyUsername     $(ProxyUsername)
```

The values are defined in a Variable Group.
With this configuration, the task works well

```
##[debug]Agent.Version=2.177.1
##[debug]Agent.ToolsDirectory=C:\Proyectos\Agent2\_work\_tool
##[debug]evaluating 0 versions
##[debug]match not found
##[debug]Querying versions list
##[debug]Agent.ProxyUrl=***
##[debug]Agent.ProxyUsername=***
##[debug]Agent.ProxyPassword=***
##[debug]Agent.ProxyBypassList=***
(node:15928) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
##[debug]evaluating 53 versions
##[debug]matched: 5.10.0
##[debug]Found the following version from the list: 5.10.0
##[debug]isExplicit: 5.10.0
##[debug]explicit? true
##[debug]Agent.Version=2.177.1
##[debug]Agent.ToolsDirectory=C:\Proyectos\Agent2\_work\_tool
##[debug]checking cache: C:\Proyectos\Agent2\_work\_tool\NuGet\5.10.0\x64
##[debug]not found
##[debug]Downloading version: 5.10.0
...
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.prependpath]C:\Proyectos\Agent2\_work\_tool\NuGet\5.10.0\x64
##[debug]set NuGetExeToolPath=C:\Proyectos\Agent2\_work\_tool\NuGet\5.10.0\x64\nuget.exe
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.setvariable variable=NuGetExeToolPath;issecret=false;]C:\Proyectos\Agent2\_work\_tool\NuGet\5.10.0\x64\nuget.exe
```

Then the problem is traslated to the second tasks. This is the generated YAML of the second tasks:

```
steps:
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet restore packages.config'
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '**/packages.config'
    feedsToUse: config
    nugetConfigPath: 'xxxxxxxxxx\NuGet.Config'
    externalFeedCredentials: 'xxxxxxxxx Basic Authentication'
```

The external Feed Credentials is a Service Connection to a private feed in another DevOps collection of the same server. I have also tried using a Service Connection with a Token and getting the same result.

This is part of the log of this task

```
Versión de NuGet detectada: 5.10.0.7240 / 5.10.0+dca1d060f38e1e02f6bfca41e25f081f19fd534b.dca1d060f38e1e02f6bfca41e25f081f19fd534b
##[debug]Quirks for 5.10.0.7240:
##[debug]    NoTfsOnPremAuthConfig
##[debug]    V2CredentialProvider
##[debug]NuGet.ForceEnableCredentialProvider=undefined
##[debug]Credential provider V1 is disabled in favor of V2 plugin.
##[debug]NuGet_ForceEnableCredentialProviderV2=undefined
##[debug]NuGetTasks.IsHostedTestEnvironment=undefined
##[debug]System.ServerType=OnPremises
##[debug]V2 credential provider is enabled.
##[debug]NuGet.ForceEnableCredentialConfig=undefined
##[debug]NuGetTasks.IsHostedTestEnvironment=undefined
##[debug]System.ServerType=OnPremises
##[debug]Credential config is disabled due to on-prem quirks.
##[debug]Setting up auth
##[debug]Discovered URL prefixes: http://xxxxxxxxx:8080/tfs/xxxxxxxx/
##[debug]NuGetTasks.ExtraUrlPrefixesForTesting=undefined
##[debug]Getting credentials for local feeds
SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
##[debug]SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
##[debug]Got auth token
##[debug]externalEndpoints=bf184c95-f3f5-4dcf-be45-9aa22eba92e9
##[debug]bf184c95-f3f5-4dcf-be45-9aa22eba92e9=http://xxxxxxx:8080/tfs/xxxxxxxx/_packaging/xxxxxxxx/nuget/v3/index.json
bf184c95-f3f5-4dcf-be45-9aa22eba92e9 exists true
##[debug]bf184c95-f3f5-4dcf-be45-9aa22eba92e9 exists true
##[debug]bf184c95-f3f5-4dcf-be45-9aa22eba92e9 auth scheme = UsernamePassword
##[debug]adding password auth entry for feed http://xxxxxxxxxxx:8080/tfs/xxxxxxxxxxx/_packaging/xxxxxxxxx/nuget/v3/index.json
##[debug]Setting up sources
##[debug]selectOrConfig=config
##[debug]nugetConfigPath=C:\Proyectos\Agent2\_work\1\s\xxxxxxxx\NuGet.Config
##[debug]check path : C:\Proyectos\Agent2\_work\1\s\xxxxxxxx\NuGet.Config
##[debug]nugetConfigPath=C:\Proyectos\Agent2\_work\1\s\xxxxxxxx\NuGet.Config
##[debug]Absolute path for pathSegments: C:\Proyectos\Agent2\_work\1\s\xxxxxxxx\NuGet.Config = C:\Proyectos\Agent2\_work\1\s\xxxxxxxx\NuGet.Config
##[debug]build.sourcesDirectory=C:\Proyectos\Agent2\_work\1\s
##[debug]Absolute path for pathSegments: C:\Proyectos\Agent2\_work\1\s = C:\Proyectos\Agent2\_work\1\s
##[debug]nugetConfigPathpath supplied :true
##[debug]Agent.BuildDirectory=C:\Proyectos\Agent2\_work\1
##[debug]build.buildId=210
##[debug]No temp nuget.config auth
##[debug]ConfigFile: C:\Proyectos\Agent2\_work\1\s\xxxxxxxx\NuGet.Config
##[debug]Absolute path for pathSegments: C:\Proyectos\Agent2\_work\_tool\NuGet\5.10.0\x64\nuget.exe = C:\Proyectos\Agent2\_work\_tool\NuGet\5.10.0\x64\nuget.exe
##[debug]which 'C:\Proyectos\Agent2\_work\_tool\NuGet\5.10.0\x64\nuget.exe'
##[debug]found: 'C:\Proyectos\Agent2\_work\_tool\NuGet\5.10.0\x64\nuget.exe'
##[debug]which 'C:\Proyectos\Agent2\_work\_tool\NuGet\5.10.0\x64\nuget.exe'
##[debug]found: 'C:\Proyectos\Agent2\_work\_tool\NuGet\5.10.0\x64\nuget.exe'
##[debug]C:\Proyectos\Agent2\_work\_tool\NuGet\5.10.0\x64\nuget.exe arg: restore
##[debug]C:\Proyectos\Agent2\_work\_tool\NuGet\5.10.0\x64\nuget.exe arg: C:\Proyectos\Agent2\_work\1\s\xxxxxxxx\xxxxxxxx\packages.config
##[debug]C:\Proyectos\Agent2\_work\_tool\NuGet\5.10.0\x64\nuget.exe arg: -Verbosity
##[debug]C:\Proyectos\Agent2\_work\_tool\NuGet\5.10.0\x64\nuget.exe arg: Detailed
##[debug]C:\Proyectos\Agent2\_work\_tool\NuGet\5.10.0\x64\nuget.exe arg: -NonInteractive
##[debug]C:\Proyectos\Agent2\_work\_tool\NuGet\5.10.0\x64\nuget.exe arg: -ConfigFile
##[debug]C:\Proyectos\Agent2\_work\_tool\NuGet\5.10.0\x64\nuget.exe arg: C:\Proyectos\Agent2\_work\1\s\xxxxxxxx\NuGet.Config
##[debug]Agent.TempDirectory=C:\Proyectos\Agent2\_work\_temp
##[debug]NUGET_PLUGINS_CACHE_PATH set to C:\Proyectos\Agent2\_work\_temp\NuGetPluginsCache
##[debug]V2 credential provider set
##[debug]credProviderPath = C:\Proyectos\Agent2\_work\_tasks\NuGetCommand_333b11bd-d341-40d9-afcf-b32d5ce6f23b\2.153.2\CredentialProviderV2\plugins\netfx\CredentialProvider.Microsoft\CredentialProvider.Microsoft.exe
##[debug]Detected external credentials for:
##[debug]http://xxxxxxxx:8080/tfs/xxxxxxxx/_packaging/xxxxxxxx/nuget/v3/index.json
##[debug]agent.proxyurl=***
##[debug]agent.proxyusername=***
##[debug]agent.proxypassword=***
##[debug]Adding environment variable for NuGet proxy: http://***:***@yyyyyyyyyyy:8080/
##[debug]Agent.ProxyBypassList=***
##[debug]Getting sources from NuGet.config in this location: C:\Proyectos\Agent2\_work\1\s\xxxxxxxx\NuGet.Config
##[debug]Adding environment variable for NuGet proxy bypass: xxxxxxxx
##[debug]exec tool: C:\Proyectos\Agent2\_work\_tool\NuGet\5.10.0\x64\nuget.exe
##[debug]arguments:
##[debug]   restore
##[debug]   C:\Proyectos\Agent2\_work\1\s\xxxxxxxx\xxxxxxxx\packages.config
##[debug]   -Verbosity
##[debug]   Detailed
##[debug]   -NonInteractive
##[debug]   -ConfigFile
##[debug]   C:\Proyectos\Agent2\_work\1\s\xxxxxxxx\NuGet.Config
[command]C:\Proyectos\Agent2\_work\_tool\NuGet\5.10.0\x64\nuget.exe restore C:\Proyectos\Agent2\_work\1\s\xxxxxxxx\xxxxxxxx\packages.config -Verbosity Detailed -NonInteractive -ConfigFile C:\Proyectos\Agent2\_work\1\s\xxxxxxxx\NuGet.Config
##[debug]Re-evaluate condition on job cancellation for step: 'NuGet restore packages.config'.
##[error]The operation was canceled.
```

The task hangs and I must cancel it.

Could you help me to find what I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the right process to get it working properly.

- Install the agent.
- Create a file named .proxybypass including the URLs to bypass the proxy in the agent directory:

  - I use the command `echo *urltobypass* > .proxybypass`
- Configure the agent with proxy parameters configuration:

  - `.\config.cmd --proxyurl *YourProxyUrl* --proxyusername *YourProxyUser* --proxypassword *YourProxyPassword*`

With these steps to configure the agent the tasks execute properly.

[Run a self-hosted agent behind a web proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/proxy?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows)